# Efficient way to list files on a backup with non-zero size?

Tags: windows-10, restore

I have an *old HDD* that crashed during Windows 10 Update, and it's stuck at 75% update.

I'm now trying to extract the User files from the old HDD, *but my extraction method is giving me a large directory tree with many 0-size files.*

Without opening up each folder, how can I make a list of all files (ideally as **path/to/file**) of non-zero file size on the *restore HDD*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell ---**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <RestoreHDD> -File -Recurse |
  where Length -ne 0 |
    select -expand FullName |
Sort | Out-File C:\WhereEver\NonZero.txt
```